# Finding a polynomial mod 5: What did they do here?

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading through this solution for the problem below.

[image]

The given solution is this:

[image]

What I don't quite understand is how they got say from $\frac{1}{3}(X-2)(X-4)$ to be 'equal' to $2(X-2)(X-4)$.

How did they go from one step to the other? I am not quite understanding this.

Comment: $\frac13\equiv2\pmod5$

Answer (score 3):

Modulo 5 we have
$$2 \cdot 3=1 \pmod{5}$$

Therefore the inverse of $3$, which they denote by $\frac{1}{3}$ is $2$.
Intuitively, multiplication by $2$ cancels $3$, so in modulo 5 arithmetic, this multiplication is exactly like division by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

All my arithmetic is modulo 5:

$5(X-2)(X-4)=0$

Any of ${1,2,3,4}$ when multiplied by $3$ is non-zero, so

$\frac{5}{3} (X-2)(X-4)=0 \Rightarrow$

$ \frac{6}{3} (X-2)(X-4)- \frac{1}{3} (X-2)(X-4)=0$

Hence $ \frac{1}{3} (X-2)(X-4)= 2(X-2)(X-4)$